# Graph - Modeling dependencies into parallelism/serialism

Tags: javascript

How do I take a set of dependencies and model them as a serial and parallel actions?

For example:

U1 depends upon U2

could be a serial representation of

```
S: [U1, U2]
```

U1 and U2 are not dependent would be a parallel representation.

```
P: [U1, U2]
```

S means serial, and P means parallel.  In this example U refers to a URL that points to a resource.

In parallel resources the ordering does not matter.  In serial resources the ordering does matter.

I'm trying to build a resource loader.

It only needs to work with the local server.  Also, it only uses Ajax get requests to load resources.

But I want to a language/syntax to model the complexity of dependent resources.

**Clarification and Examples**

This is for learning/later implementation.  No outside libraries unless you can relate the syntax they use for loading to the question.

**Example 1**

Jqueryui depends upon jquery.  This would be represented as...

```
S: [U-jquery, U-jqueryui]
```

**Example 2**

jquery.js does not depend upon underscore.js.  This would be represented as...

```
P: [U-jquery, U-underscore]
```

**Example 3**

backbone.js depends upon both underscore.js and jquery.js

```
P:[U-underscore, U-jquery] // group1
S:[some_notation to represent group1, U-backbone.js]
```

Comment: As long as you don't have a circular dependency you can always build a dependency forest, which consists only of directed trees and/or sole nodes. On the trees you can simply use DFS. You then start by adding all roots or single nodes into a queue and add other resources to the queue when their dependency has been loaded. (note that if a resource has several dependencies you cannot model your dependencies as a forest, but it stays acyclic and you can use a similar approach).

Comment: @livingston_mechanical Erm, it's from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/).

Comment: @Zeta - What "similar approach" do you suggest.  Example 3 is the problem I'm trying to solve?

Comment: ... a directed acyclic graph? ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: @livingston_mechanical: A directed acyclic graph. Every path from the starting point can be done in parallel, however if a node has more than one incident edges you have to wait for all dependencies being loaded. By the way, I would represent example 3 as `P:[U-underscore, U-jquery] S:[U-underscore, U-backbone-js] S:[U-jquery, U-backbone.js]`, showing the original dependency, but they are equivalent.

Comment: ...So how do I create this directed acyclic graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No outside libraries unless you can relate the syntax they use for loading to the question.

You might want to have a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and how it specifies its dependencies. MediaWiki's [ResourceLoader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) is also quite interesting, and though the JS dependency map is dynamically generated by the PHP script its structure might be relevant.

> Jqueryui depends upon jquery. This would be represented as...
>
> ```
> S: [U-jquery, U-jqueryui]
> ```

Possible, why not. However I'm not sure if you want to invent your own DSL for dependency management; if you rather want to stick with standard JSON / object literals I'd propose to use keys of an object for the modules whose dependencies you declare, and then lists as values:

```
deps = {
    "U-jqueryui": /*depends on*/ ["U-jquery" /*and nothing else*/]
};
```

> jquery.js does not depend upon underscore.js. This would be represented as...
>
> ```
> P: [U-jquery, U-underscore]
> ```

I don't understand. Why would you need to explicitly declare that? Everything that is unrelated (does not [explicitly] depend on each other somehow) should default to unordered loading/execution. Otherwise you would have an exponential amount of P-declarations for independent modules; and what should happen if you miss one?

> backbone.js depends upon both underscore.js and jquery.js
>
> ```
> P:[U-underscore, U-jquery] // group1
> S:[some_notation to represent group1, U-backbone.js]
> ```

I would just use the same form as in example #1:

```
deps = {
    "U-backbone.js": /*depends on*/ ["U-underscore", /*and*/ "U-jquery"]
};
```

If you really need groups for something, you can create them like a module without a body, that just loads all its dependencies and provides them. In your loader code then make some exceptions for them (based on the name not starting with `U-` maybe?) so they don't fire actual ajax requests. Your final dependency object will then look like

```
deps = {
    "U-jqueryui": ["U-jquery"],
    "group1": ["U-underscore", "U-jquery"],
    "U-backbone.js": ["group1"]
};
```

Comment: ...this is good...one thing I did not mention...was that all my resources are loaded as ajax text...and I made the choice to fire all the ajax requests at once....so I simply need to "shift" your `deps = {}`, i.e. the way you modeled dependencies, into an impementation into code....so I fire off requests like this .... A1, A2, A3, A4 ... and they come back in any order...I take that stream of random responses ( or asynchronous have you ) and make sure they are loaded as soon as possible with out breaking `deps = {}`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: ...I believe this has to be done by a complex data structure per the additional questions I posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853948/how-to-implement-a-dependency-tree-or-similar-for-resource-dependencies

Answer (score -1):

Check `Modernizr.load`:

> There’s a good chance that you’re not terribly unhappy with your
>   script downloading speeds now, but you’ll be happy to know that
>   Modernizr.load does not slow anything down, and can sometimes offer a
>   small boost in performance by loading scripts asynchronously and in
>   parallel. There’s a lot of variables to weigh in this area, so we
>   suggest that you try a few things to make sure you’re getting maximum
>   performance for your specific situation.

http://modernizr.com/docs/

Comment: *"This is for learning/later implementation. No outside libraries unless you can relate the syntax they use for loading to the question."*