# Graphs - How to model dependent resources?

Tags: javascript

With out libraries, I'm trying to learn data structures.

I have these dependencies

```
jquery.js->jqueryui.js

(underscores.js, jquery.js) -> backbone.js
```

Bascially, jqueryui depends upon jquery.  Bacbkone depends on both underscore and jquery.  Jquery and underscore are not related.

I want to create a dependency tree have you to "shed light" on these relations.

I was told this is how it is done on this [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724403/modeling-dependencies-into-parallelism-serialism).  Particularly this comment.

> As long as you don't have a circular dependency you can always build a
>   dependency forest, which consists only of directed trees and/or sole
>   nodes. On the trees you can simply use DFS. You then start by adding
>   all roots or single nodes into a queue and add other resources to the
>   queue when their dependency has been loaded. (note that if a resource
>   has several dependencies you cannot model your dependencies as a
>   forest, but it stays acyclic and you can use a similar approach). –
>   Zeta

... so I do have resources with multiple dependencies, so I can't use a dependency forest.

...further discussion has suggested a directed acyclic graph.

> A directed acyclic graph. Every path from the starting point can be
>   done in parallel, however if a node has more than one incident edges
>   you have to wait for all dependencies being loaded. By the way, I
>   would represent example 3 as P:[U-underscore, U-jquery]
>   S:[U-underscore, U-backbone-js] S:[U-jquery, U-backbone.js], showing
>   the original dependency, but they are equivalent

Can I use a dependency tree?  If not what data structure is suggested to model complex dependencies...and and finally how do I implement it?

Comment: Did you look at http://yepnopejs.com/?

Comment: Polyfills are small javascript compatibility snippets that can be used to patch browser so it behaves more standards compliant. An example is adding ``indexOf`` to the `Array` prototype on certain browser versions.

Comment: "*I'm trying to learn data structures*" - Do you know at all what a tree, forest, or DAG is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have solved this problem, albeit its a long time ago. Let the dependencies be described like this:

- Module A

  - Module X
  - Module Y
- Module B

  - Module X
  - Module A
- Module C

  - Module A
  - Module B

Which means that Module A depends on Module X and Module Y - and so forth.

Iterate over the leaves in this forest and for each leaf with no dependencies (look that up at the base), put the leaf in the load queue and remove it from the forest, so first pass yields:

- Module A
- Module B

  - Module A
- Module C

  - Module A
  - Module B

Queue: Module X, Module Y.

Second pass:

- Module B
- Module C

  - Module B

Queue: Module X, Module Y, Module A.

...and so forth. Modules found in the same pass can be loaded in parallel, so a way to represent this could be:

```
[[Module X, Module Y], [Module A], [Module B], [Module C]]
```

Which means that Module X and Module Y should be loaded first and that they can be loaded in parallel. The rest must be loaded sequentially.

My biggest concern with the approach above is that it has complexity O(n^2). It should be possible to improve. Detecting cycles can easily be done with a lookup map.

Comment: ... your first step, if there no dependencies, put it in the queue, in what order, you did not mention that, you just put X than Y , but did not specify how you ordered them? ... are you implying that it does not matter b.c. they have no dependencies, what about modules which depend on them, should that effect it ... i.e. if y has 10 things waiting on it and x only has 1, wouldn't it make more sense to put y first?

Comment: Module X and Module Y were selected because they fulfilled two criteria (1) being leaves in the forest and (2) not depending on anything (i. e. not being roots). Since they were both found in the same pass, the order is not given - you can load them in any order or in parallel. And yes - the order is irrelevant since they aren't depending on anything (in the pass where they were queued). This is a general rule for all passes.

Comment: My approach doesn't take timing into account. If you want to identify bottlenecks, you can use a weight to order the modules that are allowed to load in parallel. The weights could be calculated on how many other modules depend on them or just their maximum depth. But anyway - many other factors come into play here, such as size versus bandwith as well as the stuff the modules will do once they wake up.

Comment: thanks, have you tried looking at this from a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) perspective?

Comment: Well.... the list of modules can be mapped to a disconnected directed acyclic graph, so in that sense, yes :)

Comment: ... why are they disconnected ... R1 -> R2 ... R1 depends upon R2 ... this is a connection correct with a direction from R1 to R2 correct?

Comment: You are right. I was only referring to the example where I assumed that the root node called "Module A" is different from the leaf node called "Module A". It doesn't really have any practical implications AFAIK, apart from the fact that I am not very good at communication.

Comment: Sorry - no. I wrote the code in the late nineties and I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your asking about modular code *without* a library but using libraries as the modules (jQuery, jQuery-ui, etc.), It seems as this question is actually two questions.

1. How can you make sense of the many external libraries you have (sans depending on linear loading with script tags)
2. How do you implement modular dependencies

To answer the first one, it is a bit complicated. Most modular dependency designed require some wrapping around the modules to keep track of them. Most JS libraries do not use such systems in the assumption that they will be loaded via script tags (linear loading). Some systems such as [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) will provide a modified version to be compatible while others attempt to inject script tags into the page in a predefined order. The more popular solutions are to use a build tool that will concatenate the different library file you have into one large file that will order them in the correct order.

Most libraries are nice and will contain their code inside to prevent clobbering other scripts that also load. Even jQuery offers a `noConflict()` method to prevent the `$` syntax from clobbering what other libraries might expect (for example [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com)).

The answer to handling dependencies with external libraries depends on either modifying the libraries to comply with what ever modular system you have or to have a external system such as a build environment that will (for lack of a better term) compile them into the correct order.

That's the bad news. The good news is code you control can in fact use a dependency tree that works very well. [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) is one prime example of doing this. Although a system such as [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) or [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) can be very powerful you can implement a simple dependency API on your own.

Taking from [Rye.js](http://ryejs.com/) as the [example](https://github.com/ryejs/rye/blob/master/lib/rye.js#L36) of how to implement your own modular system for your code:

```
(function(global) {

  var module_list = {};

  global.require = function (module) {
    return module_list[module];
  };

  global.define = function (module, fn) {
    modules[module] = fn();
  };

})(this);
```

Then you can define your own modules:

```
define("hello_world", function() {

  function helloWorld() {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }

  return {
    sayHello: helloWorld
  };

});
```

Then in another module that depends on that one:

```
define("greetings", function() {

  var hello = require("hello_world");

  function sayAll() {
    hello.sayHello();
    alert("Good-Bye!");
  }

  return {
    sayAll: sayAll
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The data structure I've shown you in my previous answer,

```
deps = {
    "U-jqueryui": ["U-jquery"],
    "group1": ["U-underscore", "U-jquery"],
    "U-backbone.js": ["group1"]
}
```

is represents a DAG:

```
U-jquerui   U-backbone.js
     |          |
     |          v
     |       group1
     |      /     |
     v    L       v
 U-jquery    U-underscore.js
```

From this, you can extract a dependency tree, like

```
       root
      |    |
      v    v
U-jquery  U-underscore.js
```

for `group1`. The collection of all possible trees is then called a [forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_(graph_theory)).

> so I do have resources with multiple dependencies, so I can't use a dependency forest.

No, you don't. Having resources with multiple dependencies only means you need a tree instead of a queue. Where it become no ([multi-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree)/[poly-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree)) tree any more is when you have a diamond shape in your DAG diagram, for example if you had a module `U-myapp` that relies on `U-jquerui` and `U-backbone.js` - it relies on `U-jquery` "twice".

However, I don't think we really need to use any algorithms for a whole graph.

> If not what data structure is suggested to model complex dependencies

The one I've already shown you - just modeling direct dependencies. It allows you to represent a DAG (including polyforests) even if you don't need it yet.

> and and finally how do I implement it?

I'd go with memoized promises (sorry, I like them). Every promise represents the fact that a module has been loaded and executed; and we memoize (cache) them by module name so we don't start them multiple times. The code then is rather simple:

```
var modulepromises = {};
function loadAndExecute(name) {
    if (name in modulepromises) // memoized?
        return modulepromises[name]; // we're on it already!

    var dependencies = [];
    if (name in deps)
        dependencies = deps[name].map(loadAndExecute);
    // all promises for direct dependencies (indirect deps are included) combined
    // will be fulfilled already if empty array
    var depsExecuted = Promise.when(dependencies);
  
    if (name.slice(0, 2) == "U-") // if a group, don't load anything
        var file = ajaxPromiseForModulesource(name);
    
    return modulepromises[name] = /*memoize!*/ depsExecuted.then(function() {
        if (file)
            return file.then(function(code) {
                execute(code); // eval?
                return "module "+name+" executed";
            });
        return "group loaded";
    });
}
```