# Is there a better way to implement a function that runs tasks with inter-dependency in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a list of tasks that are inter-dependent:

```js
let tasks = {
  a: {
    job: function () {
      console.log('Tasks A running')
    },
    dependency: ['c', 'b'],
  },
  b: {
    job: function () {
      console.log('Tasks B running')
    },
    dependency: [],
  },
  c: {
    job: function () {
      console.log('Tasks C running')
    },
    dependency: ['b'],
  },
}
```

The idea is that we should first run the task that with no dependency, which `b` in this case, and once it runs, we run `c` which depends on `b` and then finally we run `a`.

The solution I came up with is

```js
function runTasks(tasks) {
  while (Object.keys(tasks).length) {
    for (let [key, { dependency, job }] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
      if (dependency.length === 0) {
        job()
        deleteAllOccurance(tasks, key)
        delete tasks[key]
      }
    }
  }
}

function deleteAllOccurance(tasks, name) {
  for (let [key, { dependency }] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
    tasks[key].dependency = dependency.filter((x) => x !== name)
  }
}
runTasks(tasks)
```

It worked but I think it is not ideal:

1. I mutated the original `tasks` object
2. it might be slow because for every time we need to find all the occurrences in other tasks' dependency lists.

Therefore I am trying to find a better solution here.

Comment: See also [Task Runner in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72137667/1048572) or [Graphs - How to model dependent resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853948/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
function runTasks(tasks) {
  const done = {};
  const execute = (name) => {
    if (!done[name]) {
      const {dependency, job} = tasks[name];
      dependency.forEach(execute);
      job();
      done[name] = true;
    }
  }
  for (const name in tasks) {
    execute(name);
  }
}
```

It's easy to see that this algorithm will execute each task exactly once, and dependencies before the jobs themselves.

The time complexity is `O(t+d)`, where `t` is the number of tasks, and `d` the total number of dependencies. Your code is `O(t^2 + td)`.

For instance, if we look at the worst possible dependency graph, where a task depends on all previous tasks, `d = t*(t-1)/2`, making my algorithm `O(t^2)`, but yours `O(t^3)`. Or if we look at a minimal dependency graph, where each tasks depends on a single previous task, `d = t-1`, making my algorithm `O(t)`, but yours `O(t^2)`.

Also, if the dependency graph were to contain a cycle, my code throws an error, while your code would loop forever.

Comment: Nice solution, basically the same as what I did with a `Set` :-)

Comment: "*if the dependency graph were to contain a cycle, my code throws an error*" - no it doesn't, as you `execute()` the dependencies *before* setting `done[name] = true;` - you'll just get a stack overflow at some point. It could trivially be adjusted to throw when finding a cycle, however.

Comment: a stack overflow is an error, is it not? What I meant to say is that I find it better to throw than to loop indefinitely if given an invalid input. But yes, if cycles are a real concern one would likely add explicit cycle detection code to detect the cycle before the stack overflows, and emit a nicer diagnostic that identifies the cycle detected.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now

Comment: curious about the time complexity anaylysis here: why is that my original approach has a time complexity of `O(t + td)`? I thought it'd be `O(t^2d)` as first there is a while loop `while (Object.keys(tasks).length)` inside that while loop there is a `for` loop. Doesn't that make time complexity `O(t^2)` already?

Comment: You're right, I was so focused on the iteration in `deleteAllOccurence` that I missed the inefficiency in task iteration. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just run them all, recurse on dependencies, and memoise the results:

```js
const tasks={a:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks A running")},dependency:["c","b"]},b:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks B running")},dependency:[]},c:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks C running")},dependency:["b"]}};

const done = new Set();
function run(name) {
  if (done.has(name)) return;
  done.add(name);
  const task = tasks[name];
  for (const dep of task.dependency) run(dep);
  task.job();
}
for (const name in tasks) run(name);
```

You can extend this to detect circular dependencies and throw an exception.

Comment: thanks. is this going to a runtime complexity of `O(t)` t being the number of tasks? Can I ask how we can detect circular dependencies and guard against it?

Comment: Yes, it's linear in the number of tasks and their dependencies, making it the optimal solution.

Comment: Guarding against circular dependencies currently happens by marking a task as done before evaluating its dependencies, so it might run some tasks whose dependencies are not met (because they are still being prepared to run). You can change this by using a `Map` instead of a `Set` (or a second `Set`) to distinguish "visited" from "executed" tasks, and throw when you meet one that already was visited.

Comment: Is there a way to make this async?

Comment: @retorquere [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72142328/1048572). What specifically do you want to be async?

Comment: The job functions. The sync version (unsuprisingly) works (https://gist.github.com/retorquere/b95948dd4000ee15d05e33cad604989b), but the naive asyncification https://gist.github.com/retorquere/4955b69c744ca4d779db90f7f207cfa3 fails in the loop detection. But the answers you point to have several valid solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have a recursive function that identifies an available task, runs it, and adds its key to the finished pile. Then, that key can be removed from the object and it can recursively call itself.

```js
let tasks={a:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks A running")},dependency:["c","b"]},b:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks B running")},dependency:[]},c:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks C running")},dependency:["b"]}};

const findTask = (tasks, done = new Set()) => {
  const result = Object.entries(tasks)
    .find(([, task]) => task.dependency.every(dep => done.has(dep)))
  if (!result) {
    // done
    return;
  }
  const [key, { job }] = result;
  job();
  done.add(key);
  const { [key]: _, ...restTasks } = tasks;
  findTask(restTasks, done);
};
findTask(tasks)
```

You could also invert the dependencies by mapping each possible subtask for a task object directly onto that task object. That way, you only need to iterate over the possible subtasks for one task to see which of them have had all dependencies fulfilled, rather than over the entire input array.

This way, for example, given

```
  a: {
    dependency: ['c', 'b'],
  },
  b: {
    dependency: [],
  },
  c: {
    dependency: ['b'],
  }
```

you could first construct

```
  b: {
    dependants: ['a', 'c'],
  }, c: {
    dependants: ['a']
  }
```

and then, upon completing `b` (for example), search through only `a` and `c` to see if either of them are ready.

This could be a lot faster if the input is large, but requires some nontrivial setup ahead of time.

```js
let tasks={a:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks A running")},dependency:["c","b"]},b:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks B running")},dependency:[]},c:{job:function(){console.log("Tasks C running")},dependency:["b"]}};

const dependentsByTask = {};
for (const [key, { dependency }] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
  for (const dependent of dependency) {
    dependentsByTask[dependent] ??= [];
    dependentsByTask[dependent].push(key);
  }
}
const tasksWithDependants = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(tasks).map(
    ([key, task]) => [key, { ...task, dependantsKeys: dependentsByTask[key], id: key }]
  )
);
for (const task of Object.values(tasksWithDependants)) {
  task.dependants = (task.dependantsKeys || []).map(key => tasksWithDependants[key]);
}
const linkedTasksWithDependants = Object.values(tasksWithDependants);
const tryRunTask = (task, done = new Set()) => {
  if (!task.dependency.every(key => done.has(key))) {
    return;
  }
  task.job();
  done.add(task.id)
  for (const subtask of task.dependants) {
    tryRunTask(subtask, done);
  }
};
tryRunTask(linkedTasksWithDependants.find(task => (!task.dependency.length)));
```

Comment: does the time complexity stay the same pretty much?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const pending = new Set(Object.keys(tasks))

while (pending.size)
    for (const p of pending)
        if (!tasks[p].dependency.some(d => pending.has(d))) {
            tasks[p].job()
            pending.delete(p)
        }
```

Comment: thanks. is this going to a runtime complexity of O(t) t being the number of tasks?